# Prove that f is surjective.

Tags: real-analysis, functions

> Let $X \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be nonempty and compact, $Y \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be connected, and $f : X \to Y$ a continuous differentiable map such that $f'(x)$ is invertible for all $x \in X$. Prove that $f$ is surjective.
>   Is the assumption that $X$ be compact necessary?

I don't actually believe that the statement is true as written.
Let $X \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ be $[0,1] \times [0,1]$,  $Y \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ be $[0,2] \times [0,2]$, and $f(x_1,x_2)=x_1,x_2$. This should satisfy all of the hypotheses of the problem, but there are no $x_1, x_2$ such that $f(x_1,x_2)=(2,2)$. What am I missing?

**Edit**

Thanks to John and David for your comments.

**Edit**

Statement is not true. Again, thanks to John and David for helping me work through it.

Comment: You might even take $Y$ to be noncompact so your statement can never be correct.

Comment: @JohnMa : I don't think you can take $Y$ noncompact, as $X$ compact and $f: X\mapsto Y$ continuous imply $Y$ compact

Comment: @Tryss But $f$ is not asumed onto.

Comment: What is the inverse of $f'$ in you're example?

Comment: @JohnMa : Oh ! You're right ! :p

Comment: @DavidHill $f'$ is the identity matrix, so its inverse is also the identity matrix.

Comment: I am confused. Do your example in $1$-dimension. Take the map $f:[0,1]\to[0,2]$ given by $f(x)=x$. What is $f'$? Is it an invertible function?

Comment: @DavidHill You're right, $f'(x)$=1 which is not invertible on [0,1].

Comment: I think you are right, though. You could instead take $f(x)=x^2$...

Comment: I think you mean injective (1-to-1), not surjective (onto).

Comment: If you assume $X$ and $Y$ are _manifolds_ (without boundary) of the same dimension, you're in good shape: $f$ is an open map by the inverse function theorem, so $f(X)$ is open in $Y$, and $f(X)$ is compact, hence closed. Compactness of $X$ is essential, as the inclusion of a proper, non-empty open set $X \hookrightarrow Y$ shows.